# SQL - Setting a variable equal to ISNULL?

Tags: t-sql, set, equals, isnull

I'm confused by a line of code.

`IF @StatusCode = '71' 
      BEGIN 
        SET @VarA = Isnull(@VarC, @VarD)`

What exactly will be the result for VarA in both the situation VarC is null and is not?

Comment: Is there a specific part of the documentation for [`IsNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that you are having trouble with? Have you read the section on [return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-types) and the remarks section that follows it?

Comment: Note also that the result in `@VarA` will depend on its declared datatype. The result of `IsNull`, if its datatype differs from that of `@VarA`, will be subject to [implicit type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two codes are equivalent

```
SET @VarA = Isnull(@VarC, @VarD)
```

and

```
if @VarC is not null 
   set @VarA = @VarC 
else
  set @VarA = @VarD
```

Answer (score 0):

ISNUL is an alternative for setting values which are null to the altermative value  as in your case `Isnull(@VarC, @VarD)` if @VarC is null then value will be @var_d else @VarC itself

Answer (score 0):

ISNULL() function lets you return an alternative value when an expression is NULL.

if `@VARC` is not null, `@VarA = @VARC`.

If `@VARC` is null, `@VarA = @VarD`.